# Getting a ETA of a packet in Omnet++

Tags: omnet++

I embedded the Omnet++ simulation kernel into my application and I'm using the inet framework for my simulation. The problem I'm having is that I need to estimate at witch time a packet is going to arrive at it's destination.

So more specific: There are two EtherHost, named H0 and H1 (inet.node.ethernet.EtherHost) and one EtherSwitch named switch (inet.node.ethernet.EtherSwitch), the three are connected like this:

> H0 <-> C <-> switch <-> C <-> H1

C denotes a DatarateChannel with datarate = 100Mbps and delay = 0.1us. When the EtherAppCli in H0 sends a EtherAppReq to H1, I need to get a ETA on the EterAppReq packet during the transfer of said packet.

My first thought was to always get the encapsulating package of EtherAppReq, wich is added in the EtherLLC and EtherMAC module but this is not as simple as I thought.. I would need to change all the encapsulating functions in all the lower layers to always get a pointer to the encapsulating package, or am I wrong?

Or is there another way to get a ETA of a packet mid-transfer?

**Edit:** For my purpose I only need the arrival time at the next module, so if the packet is in the mac module of H0 I need the arrival time at the mac layer in the switch (So no multi module hops). Like when you have a cMessage you can call getArrivalTime() on the message and get a estimate of the arrival time if I'm not mistaken.

Thank you very much for the help in advance!

Answer (score 0):

It is impossible to obtain ETA of a packet in advance. 
The time of packet's arriving depends on many factors (like in real network), for example: current number of packets in host's and switch's queues, processing time in switch, number of CPU of switch, processing time of MAC layer in a host etc. Therefore at the moment of sending a packet neither the host nor simulation environment **do not know when this packet arrive a destination host**. So we prepare a model and do a simulation in order to **measure this time** and learn how some factors influence it. 
By the way: there is no H1 in your figure.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I edited my original question, I only need to get the arrival time at the next module and not the ETA of the whole trip. Sorry for not specifying that.